# Can't install PyQt4

Tags: pyqt4, python-sip

I'm trying to install the latest version of PyQt4 for windows. Riverbank doesn't provide binary installer anymore. I downloaded the source package and when I try to follow the instructions by running `python configure.py` I get an error message that I need `SIP 4.18 or later version to be installed`. I try to install sip using `pip3 install sip` (as it's explained here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SIP/4.19), but it fails to install.

Would you please help me in this?

Comment: what is your compiler?

Comment: I'm using Anaconda 3

Comment: If you are going to compile the source code you need a compiler for example visual (msvc), and seeing that you confuse between a compiler and conda I recommend looking at conda pyqt4 precompiled and do not use the source code since I see that you are a beginner.

Comment: In addition to compile you need to have qt4 installed.

Comment: for example the following package: https://anaconda.org/ales-erjavec/pyqt4

Comment: I'm a beginner indeed, and the point is that I'm having difficulty installing  pyqt4